# toggle cubeportfolio not pushing down next content

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I am using cubeportfolio to get masonry filterable portfolio. Worked like a charm, but then I wanted to add a toggle inside the cbp-item.
This is the result (watch it on mobile): http://www.lichaamengeest.be/AA.php

You can see that, when toggling the content in the first cbp-item, the content comes up behind the cbp-item below, instead of the toggle content pushing the next cbp-item downwards. The height is not set fixed, so it should move freely.

The coder of cubeportfolio told me to add this code
`jQuery('.cbp').cubeportfolio('layout');` But my unanswered question is: where and how to add that code? Here's the js file with toggle code: http://www.lichaamengeest.be/scripts/custom.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the „position: absolute” on the „.cbp-item”. If you wrote the toggle function on your own try to get the height of the box and add this as new position for the following box, when you click on to toggle. So that it's recalculated it after every click.